# Nondegenerate linear maps functorially associated to algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, duality, traces

In the sequel, "$k$-algebra" means "associative unital finite dimensional $k$-algebra.

Apologies for the very long exposition.

If $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $s:A\to k$ is $k$-linear, we say that $s$ is $\mathit{nondegenerate}$ if for all $x\in A$, $s(xa)=0$ for all $a\in A\Rightarrow x=0$ (maybe I need to assume right nondegeneracy as well, I don't know)

Let us fix a base field $k$.
I would like to understand the existence and "uniqueness" of nondegenerate linear maps functorially associated to algebras in the sense that the assignment $A\mapsto s_A$ needs to satisfy the following conditions:

(1) for all field extensions $K/k$ and for all morphisms $\varphi:A\to B$ of $K$-algebras, we have $s_A=s_B\circ\varphi$;

(2) for any morphism of field extensions of $k$ $f:K\to L$, and for all $K$-algebras $A$, and all $a\in A$, we have $s_{A\otimes_K L}(a\otimes 1)=f(s_A(a))$, where the tensor product is taken with respect to $f$;

(3) for all field extensions $K/k$ and for all for all $K$-algebras $A$, the linear map $s_A$ is nondegenerate.

Of course, I do not expect such an assignment to exist for **all** $k$-algebras (even if the dimension is fixed), but before precising more the context, notice that there is always an obvious assignement satisfying (1) and (2), namely the trace map: if $A$ is a $K$-algebra, we denote by $t_A$ the linear map $t_A:a\in A\mapsto tr(\ell_a)$, where $\ell_a$ is the endomorphism of left multiplication by $a$.

The problem is that $t_A$ is not always non degenerate. It is even the zero map if $E$ is an inseparable field extension of $k$, for example. The following theorem is known (I found it browsing the web, but forgot to write down the reference. I'll find it later for those who are interested)

**Thm** If $char(k)=0$, i$t_A$ is nondegenerate if and only if $A$ is a separable $k$-algebra.

If $char(k)$ divides the dimension of $A$, then $t_A$ is the zero map. However, if $A$ is separable, there is a notion of **reduced trace**, which satisfies (1),(2) and (3), so for separable algebras, assignments satisfying (1),(2),(3) exist, in every characteristic.

From now on, I will fix  a $k$-algebra $B$, and only consider $K$-algebras $A$ such that $A\otimes_K K_{alg}\simeq B\otimes_K K_{alg}$. Such algebras will be called **$B$-forms.**

If $B$ is a direct product of matrices, we then recover separable algebras.

Now for the questions:

**Q1** Fixing $B$ and restricting to $B$-forms, does there exist assignments satisfying (1),(2),(3)  ?

**Q1'** If the answer to Q1 is no, do you know examples of $B$, other than a direct product of matrices, such that Q1 has a positive answer ?

**Q2** Assume we are in the case where Q1 has a positive answer (e.g. the case of separable algebras), is such assignment unique up to multiplication by an element of $k$ or perhaps more reasonably by an element of $Z(B)$?

**My thoughts** I think that unfortunately, answer to Q1 is NO for arbitrary $B$. I have not finished my computations yet, but I think that if $B=K[X]/(X^2)$ any assignment satisfying (1) and (2) is identically zero.
Can anyone confirm ?

However, I am pretty much convinced that answer to Q2 is YES, but I cannot figure a way to prove it yet. Note that (2) implies that $s_A$ is invariant under any $k$-algebra automorphism of $A$.

If $A$ is a $K$-algebra ($K/k$ is a field extension) and $s_A$ and $s'_A$ are non degenerate assignments, then there exists $\alpha\in A$ such that $s'_A(a)=s_A(\alpha a)$ for all $a\in A$ by non degeneracy. A non degeneracy argument then shows that $\varphi(\alpha)=\alpha$ for all automorphisms $\varphi$ of the $k$-algebra $A$. In particular, applying this to inner automorphisms show that

(*) $\alpha a=a\alpha$ for all $a\in A^\times$.

**Side question.** If $\alpha$ satisfies $(*)$, does it implies that $\alpha\in Z(A)$ ? i'll be happy to assume $K$ infinite if necessary.

If this is true, I think that the fact that $A$ is a $B$-form must imply that in fact $\alpha\in B_0$ , and so we should have $\alpha\in Z(B)$. Can someone confirm ?

I have absolutely no clue regarding Q1', but I would really really be interested in an example of $B$ such that Q1 has a positive answer, for a $B$ which is not a  direct product of matrices. Unfortunately, I have the intuition that such $B$ do not exist...

Thanks for reading this long message.

Greg

Comment: If $A{k[x]/x^2$ and $t(a+bx)=b$, it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure this will be functorial in A. We want a functorial assignment which worls for all algebras A isomorphic to some fixed B over an algebraic closure..